# Flask & pytest : How to make multiple test_clients requesting a same endpoint concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, flask, concurrency, pytest, httpclient

I am trying to test how my Flask server would handle concurrent requests on a same endpoint.

For that, I tried to launch several test clients instanciated from my app, and make them requesting this endpoint through the use of Threads.

However, it seems that these requests are only handled sequentially by the server. I think it is because there is an option to activate, when running the app, in order to enable concurrent requests handling :

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

But the thing is, I can't figure how to set this option when running pytest.
I can't even understand which portion of my code is first called when running pytest. Does it even launch app.run() ?

Any idea on how to set this "threaded" argument at True when running pytest?

Comment: Seems like locust(https://locust.io/) would be better fit here.

Comment: Or probably this : https://github.com/browsertron/pytest-parallel

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use coroutine event loops inside your pytest and run the requests into different executors.

For instance, let's say that you are using Flask test client context manager as a fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client
    del app
```

Then, on your test method, add the asyncio mark and call the endpoints using executors (learn more about asyncio [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html))

```py
import mark
import asyncio
from flask.testing import FlaskClient

def post(app_client: FlaskClient, endpoint, data):
    return app_client.post(endpoint, json=data)

@mark.asyncio
async def test_concurrent_requests(app_client: FlaskClient):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t1 = loop.run_in_executor(None, post, app_client, "/endpoint1", {"foo": "baz"})
    t2 = loop.run_in_executor(None, post, app_client, "/endpoint1", {"foo": "baz"})
```

Both requests will run in parallel in different threads, as they are running inside executors.

NOTE: If you want the response back, due to how Flask cleans up the data, it will throw a `LookUpError`. Then, you'd like to wrap the context generator on the client fixture with a `try except`